# Access Query converts Sharepoint Name to number

Tags: sql, ms-access, sharepoint-list

Any idea why SharePoint converts the names of people (assigned to each record) from a SharePoint list to numbers when appended to a new table?

Code looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 
( ID, [Party Name], Status, [Date Started], [Date Finalized], [Assigned to] )

SELECT
    [SharepointList].N_PERS
    , [SharepointList].Name
    , [SharepointList].Status
    , [SharepointList].[Date Started]
    , [SharepointList].[Date Finalized]
    , [SharepointList].[Assigned to]
FROM
    [SharepointList];
```

Comment: It may just be the ID if the sharepoint list is from a query in the background, say username, selecting from a drop down from another list.  If so you can import the list and join, or it may be possible to use multivalue fields in the query https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-lookup-and-multivalued-fields-in-queries-6f64f92d-659f-411c-9503-b6624e1e323a

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint has that "same" ability as access - it can create lookup fields - and they often cause more pain then they fix. So, in access, if you define a lookup at the table level, then the name (text from the other table shows). but if you run a report and group by, it groups by on the underlying "id" that is saved.

So, in effect, behind the scene, there REALLY is a related table.

You have to re-write the query, and in the query builder drop in the OTHER table being used for user(s).  So, while the one table "looks" like one table, it is in fact a related table.

If you want the actual text name, you have to build a query with the other "user" table joined in.

Try loading up the access query builder, the other columns as "text" may well be displayed.